# Is there a reference behind "Though we are exposed to the same elements, thou art red whilst I am yellow" in Grisaia no Rakuen?

Tags: grisaia

In "The Cocoon of Caprice II" (Episode 2) JB says "Though we are exposed to the same elements, thou art red, whilst I am yellow" in a way that seems to come off as a quote, but I can't find any references on it. I feel like she said it in one of the prequel episodes as well, but it just seems like an interesting thing to say with no context.

Can someone elucidate the meaning or context of this further for me?

[image: JB speaking to Yuuji]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a reference to a poem by [Saneatsu Mushanokōji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saneatsu_Mushanok%C5%8Dji):

> Persimmon and Yuzu
>
> Though exposed to the same winds and rains
> Thou art sweet, whilst I am sour
> Thou art red, whilst I am yellow
> While people praise thee
> They do not forsake me either

(Text found [here](https://soraphoto.exblog.jp/3338889/) in Japanese. TL by me.)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the effort! I'm glad I asked; this is lovely.